# C# Functional Call Transaction Id

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a windows application in C# and for every event like button click or tab change a transaction id is required that will exist within that event function flow only. It is purely for grouping log messages based on generated transaction ids.

I need help to generate and kill the transaction id for the function flow from any particular event. And in case of multi-threading and asynchronous calls also.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: To generate, you could just use a guid. I don’t know what you mean by “kill.”

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question that is unclear. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.